# Is it possible to make KVR800D2D4P6 memory work on Intel DQ45CB

Tags: memory, hardware

We have a self-made Intel DQ45CB based server/workstation in a server case in a datacenter.
The system works just fine for it's purposes, but would do perfectly with a small memory upgrade.

I've puchased an already used RAM modules of DDR2 DIMM Memory: KVR800D2D4P6/4G memory. Two sticks.

When I put them into a server, it won't start and two buzzer sounds are played.

Intel site says it supports KVR800D2D4N6 memory for sure. I didn't think one letter would cast a RAM module unusable on the motherboard, but will think twice next time.

Perhaps there is an opportunity to get it to work? Is there a BIOS firmware that would allow such RAM to be used, an update perhaps? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The P in your RAM stands for 'parity' and your motherboard doesn't support it.

> I didn't think one letter would cast a RAM module unusable on the
>   motherboard, but will think twice next time.

It's not the letter it objects to, it's the fact that you're trying to use incompatible memory.  You indicate that you checked the HCL, this isn't listed and now you're surprised that it doesn't work?

Comment: The list of memory modules on Intel site states it lists the tested memory, which doesn't necessarily means it is a complete list of supported memory modules. I think.